# Why am I encountering an error with comm.Bcast() function in mpi4py when broadcasting a numpy array?

Tags: python, error-handling, mpi, broadcast, truncate

I am currently implementing parallel Python computation using the mpi4py package. In my code, there is a segment that uses `comm.Bcast()` to broadcast a list from rank0 to other ranks. However, I encountered an error. I have simplified the problematic code segment as follows:

```
if rank == 0:
    char = [0.1, 0.1, 0.1]
    char = np.array(char)
else:
    char = np.zeros(3, dtype=np.float64)
comm.Bcast(char, root=0)
```

After executing this code, half of the ranks successfully receive the broadcasted information (I am using 48 ranks, and upon printing 'char' after the Bcast operation, 24 ranks successfully print the array), while the other half encounter an error with the message:

```
mpi4py.MPI.Exception: MPI_ERR_TRUNCATE: message truncated
```

I am confident that there is nothing wrong with this code segment itself. I isolated and ran it separately, and the results were normal. I have also searched for information related to this error and found that most people encountered it due to mismatched data types with command case sensitivity (i.e., `Bcast` vs `bcast`). However, I am certain that I am using the correct numpy array and Bcast, as I have used Bcast multiple times before in my code without encountering this error.

I suspect this might be related to my preceding code. However, my preceding code is lengthy, and I am unsure of what might cause this outcome. I am also unsure of which part should be included in the question. If anyone knows what could cause this problem, I would be immensely grateful for any insights.

Comment: are you able to reproduce the issue with only the snippet you posted? if not, then the root cause is likely in the code you did not share and unless you can produce a [mcve] there is pretty much nothing to expect here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I cannot reproduce the error with just this segment alone. In fact, when I isolate this segment, the result is correct. Indeed, as you suggested, the error might lie in the preceding code. However, that code is very long. Tomorrow, I will attempt to identify a minimal segment from that code base that can reproduce the error.